# Dynamic broadcast receiver registration doesnt work for Intent MEDIA_MOUNTED

Tags: android, android-intent

Statically linked broadcast receiver works fine for

- android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
- android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED

But when I am trying to register this dynamically then it doesn't work, Any suggestion ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d( TAG, "onCreate" );

    cardReceiver = new CardReceiver();
    filter1 = new IntentFilter();
    filter1.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    filter1.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
    this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(cardReceiver, filter1);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d( TAG, "onDestroy" );
    this.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(cardReceiver);

}

public class CardReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String CARD_LOG = "isdcard";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED")){
            Log.v(CARD_LOG, "SD card mounted.");        
        } else if(action.equals("android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED")){
            Log.v(CARD_LOG, "SD card unmounted.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to add

filter1.addDataScheme("file"); which will look like

```
cardReceiver = new CardReceiver();
filter1 = new IntentFilter();
filter1.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
filter1.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
filter1.addDataScheme("file");
this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(cardReceiver, filter1);
```